# Docker Container from php:5.6-apache as root

Tags: apache, docker

This would be related to [Docker php:5.6-Apache Development Environment missing permissions on volume mount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36732334/docker-php5-6-apache-development-environment-missing-permissions-on-volume-moun)

I have tried pretty much everything to make the mounted volume be readable by `www-data`, my current solution is trying to move by scripts the folders needed by the application to `/var` and giving the proper permissions to be writable by `www-data` but that is becoming hard to maintain.

Giving the fact that it's a development environment I don't mind being a security hole so I would like to run `apache` as `root` and I get

> Error: Apache has not been designed to serve pages while running as
>   root. There are known race conditions that will allow any local user
>   to read any file on the system. If you still desire to serve pages as
>   root then add -DBIG_SECURITY_HOLE to the CFLAGS line in your
>   src/Configuration file and rebuild the server. It is strongly
>   suggested that you instead modify the User directive in your
>   httpd.conf file to list a non-root user.

Is there any easy way I can accomplish this using the docker image `php:5.6-apache`?

This is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:

    api:
        container_name: api
        privileged: true
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: apigility/Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "2020:80"
        volumes:
            - /ft/code/api:/var/www:rw
```

And this is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

USER root
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y sudo openjdk-7-jdk \
    && echo "www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

RUN apt-get install -y git zlib1g-dev libmcrypt-dev nano vim --no-install-recommends \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt zip \
    && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer \
    | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
    && a2enmod rewrite \
    && sed -i 's!/var/www/html!/var/www/public!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf \
    && echo "AllowEncodedSlashes On" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf \
    && cp /usr/src/php/php.ini-production /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini \
    && printf '[Date]\ndate.timezone=UTC' > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/timezone.ini

WORKDIR /var/www
```

Comment: Could you provide your Dockerfile and the way you try to launch your container?

Answer (score 4):

Why not to do exactly what it says in the question you referred to?

```
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data
RUN groupmod -g 1000 www-data
```

This is not a hack. It's a proper solution to the problem you have in the development environment.

Comment: yes, but for that to work you need to ssh into your docker-machine and run `sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 code /code`

Answer (score 0):

So, I managed to make the mounted data available for `www-data` by using the part of the answer in the related post but another step is required for it to work.

After you run `docker-machine start default` you need to ssh into it and run the following:

`sudo mkdir --parents /code` [where `/code` is the shared folder in virtualbox]

`sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=999,gid=999 code /code` [this is to make sure the `uid` and `gid` is 999 for the next part to work]

Then in your `Dockerfile` add

```
RUN usermod -u 999 www-data \
    && groupmod -g 999 www-data
```

After it's mounted, `/code` will have the owner `www-data`, and problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Another and better solution.

Add this in your dockerfile

```
RUN cd ~ \
    && apt-get -y install dpkg-dev debhelper libaprutil1-dev libapr1-dev libpcre3-dev liblua5.1-0-dev autotools-dev \
    && apt-get source apache2.2-common \
    && cd apache2-2.4.10 \
    && export DEB_CFLAGS_SET="-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -DBIG_SECURITY_HOLE" \
    && dpkg-buildpackage -b \
    && cd .. \
    && dpkg -i apache2-bin_2.4.10-10+deb8u7_amd64.deb \
    && dpkg -i apache2.2-common_2.4.10-10+deb8u7_amd64.deb
```

After that, you could be able to run apache as root.

PS : apache2-2.4.10, apache2-bin_2.4.10-10+deb8u7_amd64.deb and apache2.2-common_2.4.10-10+deb8u7_amd64.deb could change according to your source