# Permission problem: How to setup permissions on docker for windows for use with Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

## The problem

I'm trying to setup my developing environment using Docker for Windows for use with Wordpress. I'm using docker compose with a custom Dockerfile. This works perfectly on MacOS.
Using the exact same docker setup on Windows though gets me these messages within Wordpress.

*Trying to upload media*
[image: Trying to upload media]

*Trying to update Wordpress*
[image: Trying to update Wordpress]

Clearly, Worpress doesn't have the correct file permissions.

## What I tried

**1. Checking Docker for Windows settings and upgrading to WSL 2**

I'm using the WSL 2 based engine now, which should give [full root permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config?WT.mc_id=none-twitter-bketelsen#set-wsl-launch-settings) to all the files on the system. I upgraded to WPL 2 as I was first using the Hyper-V- based backend (with of course the correct file permissions setup), I tried to fix the problems by upgrading. No luck.

**2. Experimenting with `chmod` and `chown`**

First, I added `chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/` to the Dockerfile. As far as I know, this should give all file permissions to root. It didn't have any effect. So maybe I'm using a different user? The command `whoami` did give me root back though.
Maybe I did something wrong and the user is something else. So I added `chown -R www-data:www-data /var`, as I saw www-data should be the default Docker user and group. No luck.

Just for the fun of it, I also tried `chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/` just to be more specific in the path. Interestingly, this gave me the error `chmod: cannot access '/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/': No such file or directory`. I did link the folders though and this works (I can see in the folder structure in IntelliJ the files indeed are in /var/www/html). The `-R` option should make this recursive anyway, so it shouldn't matter.

**3. Doing all this while the container is running**

So maybe because the files were not yet present, I could not assign permissions. So I tried all this also when the container was actually running. Again, no luck.

**4. Running as user `root`**

First, I added `user: root` to the service in my `docker-compose.yml`. No Luck.
Then I added `USER root` to the Dockerfile, just below `FROM php:7.4-apache`. No luck.

**5. Using the official Wordpress image**

As you can see below, I'm using the apache image as a basis for my Dockerfile. I also tried using the wordpress:latest image directly from my `docker-compose.yml` (omitting the entire Dockerfile) and I tried using `FROM: wordpress:latest` on top of the Dockerfile. Both didn't change anything.

## My files

By now, I tried every solution I could find on the internet and nothing works. Crazy thing, all this works fine under MacOS. Here are my docker files, I hope u guys can help me out here.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    container_name: wolfpackvision.com
    ports:
    - "8080:80"
    volumes:
    - .:/var/www/html
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

#USER root

RUN apt-get update
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli

## Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

## Install PHP-GD
RUN apt-get install -y libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libfreetype6-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd

## Install xdebug
RUN apt-get install --assume-yes --fix-missing git libzip-dev libmcrypt-dev openssh-client \
    libxml2-dev libpng-dev g++ make autoconf \
    && docker-php-source extract \
    && pecl install xdebug redis \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug redis \
    && docker-php-source delete \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql soap intl zip

## Configure xdebug
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_enable=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=off" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_port=9000" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.idekey=wolfpackvision.com" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini

## Enable mod_rewrite http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html & mod_headers http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html
RUN a2enmod rewrite \
    && a2enmod headers

## Give Full folder permissions to server
#RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
#RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/
#RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/
#RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/
#RUN chmod -R 766 /var/www/html/

## Copy php.ini over
COPY ./.docker/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php

## Cleanup
RUN rm -rf /tmp/*
```

-> Please don't go warn me about 777, I know about that. This is all strictly local and I will never use this in production. Plus, if I get the permissions working, I might tighten it. First I want it to work at all.

## **Edit**

In response to @user969068.
`docker exec -it  ps aux` gives me:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.1  0.0  90652 28568 ?        Ss   11:04   0:00 apache2 -DFOREG
www-data    16  0.0  0.0  90684  8176 ?        S    11:04   0:00 apache2 -DFOREG
www-data    17  0.0  0.0  90684  8176 ?        S    11:04   0:00 apache2 -DFOREG
www-data    18  0.0  0.0  90684  8176 ?        S    11:04   0:00 apache2 -DFOREG
www-data    19  0.0  0.0  90684  8176 ?        S    11:04   0:00 apache2 -DFOREG
www-data    20  0.0  0.0  90684  8176 ?        S    11:04   0:00 apache2 -DFOREG
root        21  0.0  0.0   7640  2708 pts/0    Rs+  11:06   0:00 ps aux
```

I already tried to do what you recommended with PID 21, 1 and 16. All three had the same result; no file permissions. What am I missing here?

Comment: First you need check this - https://support.cloudways.com/how-to-resolve-wordpress-asking-for-ftp-credentials-error/

Comment: That's focussing on that FTP thing too much though. The simple fact is WordPress doesn't have the correct file permissions. Solving that will also remove that FTP message

Comment: Well, I doubt that your script/software is running as root. You need to set the file permissions for the "user" used to write those files. Who runs php? Who executed those scripts? Check for that and go from there

Comment: This is just docker which im running via cmd, using my own windows administrator account. I also went into the file explorer and changed the folders permissions to read/ write for everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help.
Turns out, the issue had nothing to do with Docker. WordPress was configured to find the uploads directory within my host folder structure, setting it to /wp-content/uploads fixed everything.

Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 5):

I think your issue with user being used is different, `php:7.4-apache` uses `www-data` as user. to confirm the user when you run ( replace php:7.4-apache with your image name)

```
docker run -d php:7.4-apache
```

and than run

```
docker exec -it YOUR_IMAGE_HASH ps aux
```

it should show you `www-data` under User columns of running processes.
Once you identify the correct user, you can add to your docker file , like

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
.....
ARG user_id=1000
RUN usermod -u $user_id www-data
```

Comment: I made an edit to show my response (couldn't get code in the comments)

Comment: Not PID, you need to provide user id, which you can find it with `docker exec -it id -u www-data`. And I noticed from ps aux you are running it as root not www-data, you can try to add root to www-data group, `usermod -a -G www-data root` , and make sure you have run in your Dockerfile to set permissions like for www-data user `RUN chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/`

Comment: Sorry for my very late response. I tried all this though in all possible ways I could find and have had no luck. Got the same issues on my mac.
My main question is, how to setup a good docker web development environment for PHP using the apache image? Are there any resources on that u can point me to? Google helped a bit on that, but all I can find are elaborate blogs that use a very specific setup, with way too many components for my needs

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in WSL but I guess your issue is not inside the container, it seems like a host permissions issue. The container process can't write to `.` directory (which means the current one when you start `docker-compose`).

Here are [some related issues](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/497)

I'd check from which user the Docker process is run and try to write from this user to the directory something.
I also recommend using [named volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#create-and-manage-volumes). I believe newly created volume should have r/w permission by default on Windows host.

Comment: I just cant get this thing to work, whatever I do. Are you willing to share how you setup docker for web development with PHP? I'm not really doing anything complicated here, that's what's frustrating me

Answer (score 0):

your issue it's related to a know [Docker bug](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/4824), a bit of it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597290/cant-change-the-permissions-of-files-folders-on-a-volume-with-docker-windows)

Basically, the issue is that windows volumes don't respect the original permissions of the files, and assign everything to root at any change after the container has been initialized, I was having a similar issue with another CMS, and finally decided to enable apache to run as root for development, so it can read the files, and normally for production, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37099831/docker-container-from-php5-6-apache-as-root) gave me some ideas on how to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer and sorry for my late response.
I tried exactly ur suggestions, but it did not work.
I actually have the same problems on my Mac now, too. So it doesn't seem to be a windows- specific problem anyway. Still, whatever I do I get the 'Is its parent directory writable by the server?' message.

How do people normally setup docker for PHP development? What am I missing? I'm not doing anything complicated here

Comment: Hi there, maybe its because i'm not a Docker expert, but there are many instances where I had just needed to start from scratch, because I got weird random issues, so I'll suggest you start by reviewing your Dockerfile/scripts and other components against the best practices https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/ and totally clean your environment, sometimes I've seen stuff getting "stuck" and things that were supposed to work, failing

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my mac and just did this. This is not the answer to this question, but it may help someone.
Can help someone using MacOS

> sudo chown -R username /Users/username/.docker/contexts